# Ranged based for loop not compiling with vector of abstract class

Tags: c++, c++11, ranged-loops

I have this piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class MyAbstract
{
    public:
    std::string id;

    virtual void doStuff() = 0;
    virtual ~MyAbstract() {}
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<MyAbstract> myList;

    for(auto item : myList)
    {
        //DoSomething
    }
}
```

But it doesn't compile with this error:

> error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'MyAbstract'

Visual Studio 2015 Error:

> cannot instantiate abstract class

Here is the code online: http://cpp.sh/3etnq

What am I missing here?!
This works:

```
for (auto it = myList.begin(); it != myList.end();)
```

Comment: "Fixing" the loop won't fix the fundamental problem:a vector of an abstract type is useless because you won't be able to store anything in it.

Comment: Let's assume I used a vector of pointers :)

Comment: If you are using vector of pointer, then you won't have this problem.

Comment: I'm guessing you want `for (auto& item : myList)` - won't solve the abstract class problem, but will prevent the copy.

Comment: You're right, guess I have to think a little bit more about my design here then ... thanks for your answers!

Comment: http://ideone.com/ZrWjSH

Comment: Thanks, Pixelchemist!